# How can I downgrade a package to certain version if apt refuses that version?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

This morning I upgraded `openssl` and `libssl` because some security updates became available:

```
# apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libssl-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12]
libssl-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 all [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12]
libssl1.0.0/xenial-updates,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12]
openssl/xenial-updates,xenial-security 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12]
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 openssl
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,996 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libssl-doc all 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 [1,079 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 [1,342 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libssl1.0.0 amd64 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 [1,083 kB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 [492 kB]
Fetched 3,996 kB in 0s (61.3 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 66394 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-doc_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13_all.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-doc (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) over (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) over (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) over (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../openssl_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) over (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libssl-doc (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
# dpkg -l | grep libssl
ii  libssl-dev:amd64                   1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13                         amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc                         1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13                         all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                  1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13                         amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
# dpkg -l | grep openssl
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64          3.4.10-4ubuntu1.4                          amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  openssl                            1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13                         amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
```

We have some CSP (Content Security Policy)/CORS related problems and I wonder if this recent upgrade causes that (because nothing else changed). I would like to downgrade from version `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13` back to `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12`, but `apt` refuses:

```
# apt install openssl=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12' for 'openssl' was not found
```

---

```
# apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13
  Candidate: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 500
        500 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.2g-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Do `apt-cache search openssl` to see available versions.

Comment: @waltinator Good idea. I added it to the question. So basically once the remote repository is updated and I upgrade my installation, the older version is kinda "gone"? Maybe I can find it in some apt cache?

Comment: BTW the technical problem turned out to be unrelated to this, but I'm still curious

Comment: @CsabaToth you can check if the file is still around in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: You can download older versions of packages from launchpad.net.

Comment: @muru That directory is empty right now. Yesterday I may seen a file, but it was one huge file, not individual debs or anything